# Meaning of OpenGL ES 2.0 Coordinate System

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

What do the coordinates in an OpenGL (I'm using OpenGL ES 2.0 for Android, but I mostly just want to understand the theory for now...) 3d world actually mean?

Say I have my translate my model matrix to x,y,z where does the model go? How far, what is a unit?

Furthermore, what if I am displaying points from a vertex buffer object, defining each to have an arbitrary x, y, and z, ranging anywhere from (-∞,∞).  What does this mean when the MVP is multiplied by this position?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A 3D point (x,y,z) is actually represented in 4D as a homogeneous point (x,y,z,1) so we
can represent all the desired transformations with a 4x4 matrix -- specifically this allows translations and perspective projections.

This point is then transformed with a 4x4 *Model-View-Projection* (MVP) matrix yielding
a point (x',y',z',w').

- The *Model Matrix* transforms a point from its local *modeling coordinates* to
  *world coordinates*. Very useful for *instancing* multiple versions of a single object.
- The *View Matrix* transforms this point into *Camera Coordinates*. In this coordinate
  system the camera is actually peering down the -z exis.
- The *Projection Matrix* then transforms the point into *clip coordinates* and ultimately
  defines the particular projection to 2D that will eventually occur 
  (e.g., orthographic or perspective)

The MVP matrix is just these three matrices all multiplied together to form the composite transformation.

For a point in *clip coordinates* to be visible it must (after projection) lie with the *clipping volume* which is an axes-aligned cube with corners at (-1,-1,-1) and (+1,+1,+1).
A point is projected by dividing through by w' -- i.e. (x',y',z',w') is mapped
to (x'/w', y'/w', z'/w') -- if these three values all lie in the interval [-1,+1] then it is visible and we say the point is in *normalized device coordinates*. This division is what allows perspective foreshortening to happen for a perspective projection.

Here is the interesting part, clipping actually occurs in 4D (before this *perspective division* occurs). So for a point to be visible, the magnitude of x', y', z' must be less than the magnitude of w'. If the point survives the clip, then the perspective divide happens.

Finally, a surviving point is mapped from *normalized device coordinates* into actual *device coordinates* by the *Viewport Transformation*. Here we have an actual device coordinate (x,y) which is a 2D address in the *frame buffer* and z is a depth value in range of the *depth buffer.* The point is then shipped off to the *rasterizer*.

In summary, the first part of the OpenGL pipeline goes like this:

1. In the vertex shader, each vertex (x,y,z,1) multiplied by MVP yielding clip coordinate (x',y',z',w').
2. The vertices are assembled into the given primiitve (e.g., triangle).
3. The primitive is clipped in 4D.
4. Perspective division yields a point in *normalized device coordinates*.
5. The viewport transform maps the point to *device coordinates* and is shipped to the rasterizer.

Modeling transformations are *affine transformations* and can be represented by matrices of the form

```
     _       _
    | a b c d |
M = | e f g h |
    | i j k l |
    | 0 0 0 1 |
     -       -
```

A point P = (x,y,z,1) is actually thought of as a column vector [x y z 1]^T and 
is transformed to P' by multiplying on the right P' = M P (at least conceptually -- the hardware may transpose evethying but its still the same thing). With an affine transformation I can scale, rotate, shear, translate ... anything that preserves parallel lines. Note that the last row of M is the identity -- that's important since we don't want M to muck with the w coordinate -- we'll do that later with the projection matrix.

Note that we can represent direction vectors (e.g., surface normals) by using w = 0 which
effectively ignores the translation component. Actually, to properly transform surface normals we use the associated *normal matrix* which the inverse transpose of M's upper 3x3 matrix:

```
        _     _  ^ -T
       | a b c |
N =    | e f g |
       | i j k |
        -     -
```

This preserves orthogonality of normals with their respective planes.

For example, below is a matrix that uniformly scales an object by s, rotates about the z-axes CCW by theta, and translates the result by (4,5,6):

```
  _                                    _
 | s * cos(theta)  -s * sin(theta) 0  4 |
 | s * sin(theta)   s * cos(theta) 0  5 |
 |      0                0         1  6 |
 |      0                0         0  1 |
  -                                    -
```

The View Transformation V is a rigid transformation that simply is a rotation and translation that changes coordinates so that the camera is at the origin and is "looking out" the -z axis.

The Projection Matrix P is where things get weird -- at least for a perspective projection. Here we have to warp the *view frustum* in to the canonical clipping cube. This is not an affine transformation. This is where the ultimate multiply by 1/w will come in handy. Here use a matrix of the form

```
 P = | a 0  0 0  |
     | 0 b  0 0  |
     | 0 0  c d  |
     | 0 0 -1 0  |
```

Note that last row is *not* the identity. The point (x,y,z,1) is mapped to
(a*x, b*y, c*z + d, -z). Later, after perspective division you get

```
 (-a*x/z, -b*y/z, -(c*z + d)/z)
```

See that division by -z -- that is where the perspective foreshortening comes from.
Since clipped vertices will have z < 0, this is actually a positive division.

Anyway, I'll leave the story there....

Answer (score 2):

When you create a graphic world, 3D, 2D - doesn't matter, you need to define a coordinate system which is consistent for this world. The way you define it doesn't really matter, as long as it's consistent.

How does this apply to OpenGL?

- Each 3D element's position will be defined by its vertexes, and any transformations you made on it (e.g. scale, translate, etc). For instance, if you're rendering a sphere whose center is at {2,3,4} and with a radius of 1, this information allows you to know where in the world the sphere is, and whether or not it should be rendered.
- In OpenGL, you define a camera - which is essentially the viewport of the user. This camera is located at a certain position, is pointed at a certain direction, and is rotates at a certain angle. In addition, the camera has a projection angle which receives the visual information it sees through a certain angle (in a sense, this could be thought of as the camera's "lens").
- Once all the world exists in the same consistent coordinate system, you allow the camera to accurately capture 3D elements floating around in your world, since the location & size of the elements are relative to the cameras position and attributes.